# STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS as connectionString (Snowflake)

Tags: php, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, odbc, database-connection

I want to have `STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` as in connectionString so that my query gets aborted if it takes more than 60sec.

Below is the sample code without the use of `STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS`. Is there a way to achieve this at any level?

**Note**: If it's possible at the query level, that will be more helpful. Query level means somehow at `$result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);` code level.

```
<?php

    $server = 'abc.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com';
    $user = 'mukul';
    $pass = 'xyz123456';
    //Define Port
    $port='443';
    $database = 'db';

    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};SERVER=$server;PORT=$port;DATABASE=$database";

    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connected";
    } else{
        die("Connection could not be established.");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table limit 50";

    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    // Get Data From Result
      while ($data[] = odbc_fetch_array($result));

      // Free Result
      odbc_free_result($result);

      // Close Connection
      odbc_close($conn);

      // Show data
      print_r($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the doc https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#statement-timeout-in-seconds, **STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS** can be set at the ACCOUNT, SESSION, or OBJECT level.

```
alter session Set statement_timeout_in_seconds = 60
```

This query will set the 60-sec timeout at the session level.